# alert message on browser close or tab close does not fire in server

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to throw alert message on page on browser or tab close and on using javascript in client side its working perfectly but while running from server it does not fire javascript event my code is

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    alert("See You");
});
```

is there any way to show message on tab close

Comment: What do you mean by it does not fire on the server? JS is client side, so I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: javascript happens client side, there is no event server side. You'd have to send a request to the server to let it know the client is closing the browser.

Comment: Browser security settings may block it.

Comment: You can't call `alert()` in the `beforeunload` handler. It's supposed to return a string, and the browser will automatically display that as an alert.

Comment: js is firing from local host but while running application from server i dont see any alert message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should check your browsers security settings. IE for example automatically trusts localhosts. But your server probably isn't in the trusted zone. More about [security in IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
.

Secondly, keep in mind that `addEventListener` is not supported by older browsers. For example Internet Explorer only supports it since IE9. These older browsers will be using `addEvent` instead.

So you could do something like this, to be sure:

```
function addEvent(object, event_type, event_handler) {
    if (object.addEventListener) {
        object.addEventListener(event_type, event_handler, false);
    } else {
        object.attachEvent("on" + event_type, handler);
    }
}
```